# Cannot delete a directory in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a directory which simply won't delete.

I have tried so many things to delete these things but it won't work.

The things i have tried so far:

- Boot in to safe mode and deleted - windows hangs and stops responding
- Used forced delete applications they become non responsive when i
  click delete on the folder or files.
- Used "take ownership" of the files which opens CMD window but doesn't complete like it does for most normal files.
- When deleting normally explorer stops responding.
- Right clicking the files and clicking properties - nothing happens.

I'm out of ideas at this point on how to get rid of them. I have attatched an image of what the images are.

[image]

Explorer "calculates" for ever until it eventually crashes and stops responding.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to a linux LiveCD? Can you try deleting from it?

Comment: I do not have linux, never used it before.

Comment: can you run chkdsk?

Comment: @AEonAX i have it open it's running now - hm it just closes after a while =/

Comment: it shows .msg - Did you closed outlook and all its process from Task Manager

Comment: @Jatin i have no process saying outlook. Could it be a service? I changed the default program to notepad now though. To see if that would free it up - didn't work(but they do open in notepad and seem to be read-able)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Easy and Free Solution for 
Files or Folders "Cannot Delete" Problems on Windows

[**IObit Unlocker**](http://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php)

Comment: Well that worked! How come this worked but my "take ownership" right click context menu did not ! Very odd but im so glad its gone!

Comment: Glad that worked for you - Not sure what was causing this.